# how to create 301 redirection for all pages except robots.txt

Tags: http-status-code-301

I have just changed my domain mydomain.com to clientdomain.com. I have created 301 rediction useing

```
Redirect 301 / http://cleintdomain.com/
```

Everything works good. But I don't want to redirect http://mydomain.com/robots.txt. How can I exclude robots.txt from redirect condition?

Comment: you might want to add which platform we're talking about unless I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: It's Apache2, .htaccess redirection